# How to send function keypress (F1..F12) to a console app in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, process, keypress, handle

I am writing a windowed .NET app in C#, which runs a third party console application via the Process class, as hidden as possible (CreateNoWindow, RedirectStandardOutput, etc.).

I've redirected it's StandardInput, so I can write whatever string I want, but not function keys or other type of special keys, as they don't have a character representation. As for me, I have to send keys F1 to F4 to the console app. The solutions I've found are for windowed app (PostMessage, SendMessage).

How can I do this for my console application?

Is there anything to do with the Handle of the Process?

Answer (score 1):

[Sendkeys.SendWait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait.aspx) may solve your problem.

Comment: SendKeys can only send keystrokes to the active application, which is unfortunately not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Function keys cannot work with stdin, an app has to call ReadConsoleInput() to be able to detect them.  That no longer works when you start the process without a console window.

Comment: There is no way to push some data to the buffer it reads, is there?

Comment: No console window == no buffer.

Comment: I'm not buying this answer.  My application gets terminated when I press CTRL-BREAK, yet it has no such call to ReadConsoleInput, so that can't possibly have anything to do with it.  Since the command console has the ability to start a process, and send a break signal to it, I can't see any reason why some other application that starts a process couldn't send the same kind of signal.

Comment: You don't have to buy it, this answer is free.  Ctrl+Break is handled specially, review SetConsoleCtrlHandler() to see how it is done.

Comment: I'm quite familiar with SetConsoleCtrlHandler as well as the default method that handles the event kernel32!CtrlRoutine which one can call directly by identifying its address and starting a remote thread with it.  I'm also familiar with GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent, which is incredibly broken and fails to work whether a console app process is started in a new process group or not and whether its started with a console window or not (whether using create_new_console, create_no_window, or detached_process process creation flags).  Even if you have to call AllocConsole and HideWindow, there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

Does [`SendKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) work (`"{F1}"`)? (the console will have to be active, though).

Comment: The console itself does not even exist as a window (Process.CreateNoWindow), so SendKeys is not applicable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't directly an answer to your question, but have you considered using MSMQ?

If your windowed application can receive those key-presses, it could pass that fact on to your console application using MSMQ. You may not have to actually pass the key-press, just the the fact that they were pressed.

I have found this [techrepublic article](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6170794.html) helpful in getting the basics of MSMQ working.